# Error when trying to run rails server after migrating from 3.0.10 to 3.1.19

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, activeadmin

I tried to follow this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1?view=comments) to migrate my 3.0.10 rails app to 3.1.10, but things didn't go as smoothly for me as they did for Ryan.  After working through some gemset dependency problems I now hit the following error when trying to launch the development server:

```
[nw0.0.1master (migrate_to_31)]$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.10 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin (NameError)
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:212:in `const_missing_from_s3_library'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/rails_projects/nw0.0.1master/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:556:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `each'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/rails_projects/nw0.0.1master/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/rails_projects/nw0.0.1master/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/rails_projects/nw0.0.1master/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/rails_projects/nw0.0.1master/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:37:in `require'
    from script/rails:37:in `<main>'
```

Here is my current Gemfile:

```
gem "pg"
gem 'pg_search'
gem 'rails', '3.1.10'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.5.5'
gem 'geocoder', '1.0.2'
gem 'devise', '1.5.3'
gem 'acts_as_api', '0.3.8'
gem 'paperclip', '~>2.4.1'
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
gem 'omniauth', :git => 'https://github.com/intridea/omniauth.git'
gem 'fb_graph', '1.9.5'
gem 'twitter', :git => 'https://github.com/sferik/twitter.git'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.0'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'formtastic', '~> 2.1.0'
gem "browser"
gem "httparty"
gem "thin"

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end


group :production, :staging do
end

group :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'annotate', '2.4.0'
    gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
    gem 'ruby-debug19', '0.11.6'
    gem 'nifty-generators', '0.4.6'
    gem 'silent-postgres'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem "mocha", '0.9.12'
    gem 'silent-postgres'
end
```

And, I've enabled the asset pipeline in application.rb.  Here is application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
# If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
# Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)

module Nw001
  class Application < Rails::Application
    
    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
    
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # JavaScript files you want as :defaults (application.js is always included).
    # config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
    
    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # Note, the migration that I use to install the unaccented module for pgs requires SQL
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
 
 #uncomment to force ssl on localhost   
#   config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, "Rack::SSL"
  end
end
```

And, made the suggested additions to my config/environments files.

Any idea how to get passed the uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin (NameError)???

I've also tried to use rails 3.1.0, which throws the same error.  I also ran `rails generate active_admin:assets` to update the active_admin assets, but no love.

#### UPDATE

On the suggestion of @andrew I created a new sample rails3.1.10 application.  Actually, what I did was delete my previous gemset for 3.1; create a new gemset using rvm; installed rails 3.1.10 into the new gemset; started using that new 3.1 gemset; and then created a new rails 3.1.10 app.  The app ran as expected.

I then took things one step further by replacing the new apps gemfile with the gemfile from the app that I'm trying to migrate to 3.1.10.  After working through a couple of dependency issues and reinserting the sqlite3 gem into the gemfile, again the new test app ran just as expected.

I then copied the test apps' gemfile back into the app that I'm trying to migrate and, still using the new 3.1 gemset, tried to load the development server.  I still got an error, and it is similar to the error listed above, but it is somewhat different.  Check it out:

```
[nw0.0.1master (master)]$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.10 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:212:in `const_missing_from_s3_library': uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin (NameError)
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/rails_projects/nw0.0.1master/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:556:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `each'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/rails_projects/nw0.0.1master/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/rails_projects/nw0.0.1master/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/rails_projects/nw0.0.1master/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/rails_projects/nw0.0.1master/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    from /Users/charlesweinberger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:37:in `require'
    from script/rails:37:in `<main>'
```

Does this new info trigger any ideas???
Thanks!

Comment: Obvious question, but did you remember to run `bundle install` before running rails server? And have you tried running `bundle exec rails s` ?

Comment: Tried the first.  Didn't try the second.  I'll try it and report back

Comment: what version of active-admin are you using?

Comment: activeadmin version = 0.5.1. I've also added `gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre'` to my gemfile, but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott could the activeadmin version cause this problem?

Comment: @Andrew, `bundle exec rails s` had no effect.

Comment: @chuckw Let's add your config/application.rb --- since you're coming from 3.0, I bet there's some sass/compass stuff in there.

Comment: @Andrew.  Added the full config/application.rb.  But I don't see anything in it that jumps out at me.  Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: hmm, I don't know. The only other thing that jumps out at me is that you're using RVM, maybe there's a problem in your settings. Can you start a new Rails 3.1 app from scratch and does it work as expected?

Comment: @andrew, I did as you suggested.  Check out the updated info.  Does this trigger any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was caused by me specifying `gem 'rake', "0.8.7"` in the gemfile.  Changed it to `gem 'rake'`, and that solved the problem.  Note, you probably don't even need to include `rake` in the gemfile as it will be included as a dependency.